# Using a semaphore

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I would like to know how can i make those thread work one after the other, and how to make the first one always run after the second one. I created a semaphore, but i not sure about how to use it.

```
public class A extends Thread {
    private int i;
    public A(int x) {
        i = x;
    }@
    Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

/** IN MAIN **/

```
A c1 = new A(5);
A c2 = new A(6);
Semaphore s = new Semaphore(1, true);
c1.start();
c2.start();

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            System.out.println("+");
        }
    }
}).start();

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(70);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            System.out.println("*");
        }

    }
}).start();
```

Comment: One after the other = sequential. Why do you want multiple threads?

Comment: To exercice me at controlling threads

Comment: This makes no sense. `start` the first thread. `join` on it. Then `start` the second thread. Then `join` on it. There's no reason to use a `Semaphore` here.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis is correct. But if you just want to learn semaphores, this isn't a bad place to start: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/09/java-concurrency-tutorial-semaphores.html

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve. Can you maybe explain the execution order that you wish to have? The first two lines are not clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - I would like to know how can i make those threads work one after the other, and
> - how to make the first one always run after the second one. I created a semaphore, but i not sure about how to use it.

You could use `join()` in your case if you want thread to finish before calling thread c2. Like so (the threads are called in thread of `main`):

```
c1.start(); // Start thread `c1` first
c1.join();  // `main` now waits for `c1` to finish
c2.start(); // Start thread `c2` next
c2.join();  // `main` now waits for `c2` to finish
```

That should answer your question.

I little bit about semaphores.

In general you cannot use a semaphore to control the order of execution of threads. A semaphore is a lock for a one or more resources. The threads that want to access the resources are competing with each other, you cannot control to whom the semaphore will grant access next.

I am aware of the "trick" in the other answer. I did not test it and it might work, but I don't think that is the right way to do it.

Here is an example that works without a sempahore:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

class A extends Thread {

    private int i;
    public A(int x) {
        i = x;
    }

    public void run() {
       System.out.println(i);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        A thread1 = new A(5);
        A thread2 = new A(6);
        thread1.start();
        thread1.join();
        thread2.start();
        thread2.join();
    }
}
```

If you want to use a semaphore (although I don't see why) then the example could look like this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

class A extends Thread {

        private int i;
        final static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1, true);

        public A(int x) {
            i = x;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {

                /*thread stops here until it gets permit to go on*/
                semaphore.acquire();
                System.out.println(i);
            /*exception must be caught or thrown*/
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }

            //CRITICAL SECTION

            semaphore.release();

        }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        A thread1 = new A(5);
        A thread2 = new A(6);
        thread1.start();
        thread1.join();
        thread2.start();
        thread2.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sry, i wasn't at home. In my exemple, there is c1 and c2 thread that can be organised with join(); as you said. Now i got it. But there is also two 'new Thread' in main that execute themselves. The semaphore is needed here, since there is no instance name to use a join() method with. With your exemple, i managed to control them too, thank you sir.

Comment: In that case use a binary semaphore with fairness option. Please feel free to upvote and accept the answer if it helped you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can model the permit in the Semaphore to mean: "allowed to run".

Since you want the first thread to be allowed to run automatically, you can't use `acquire` for the first thread, because it would compete with the second thread for the permit. So the first thread starts, assuming that it has the permit. When the first thread has completed, it `release`-es the permit. The second thread needs to `acquire` the permit to be able to start working.

First create a semaphore with zero permits (because one permit is already owned by the first thread implicitly)

```
final Semaphore s = new Semaphore(0, true);
```

The last line in the first thread should read:

```
s.release();
```

(Note that it's allowed to release without an acquire - a Semaphore just counts, it doesn't keep track of who owns which permit)

And the first line in the second thread should read:

```
s.acquireUninterruptibly();
```

(or just `acquire()` but then you'd need to catch `InterruptedException`)

Answer (score 0):

Although your problem can be solved by the 'join' feature of threads which
can force the completion of one thread before starting the next asi (as seen in)
the Elyasian example but still one must add that you are on the right track
in terms of the Semaphore route undertaken.

Semaphore s = new Semaphore(1, true);

In this statement the second parameter set to 'true' is known as the Fairness setting.

This ensures (FIFO - First In First Out ) in other words in our scenario "First come First serve" ....

ie The thread that invokes acquire first would get the permit and would finish 
its task first and only then the second thread would be able to proceed with
its execution.

So your original question.....ie

I would like to know how can i make those thread work one after the other, and how to make the first one always run after the second one

could be rephrased to

I would like to know how can i make sure that the thread that invokes acquire
first on a semaphore gets to run first always....